# RxJava(Kotlin), Observable.amb and PublishSubject is not firing

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-kotlin

We're trying to observe either a 15s interval, or whenever we're firing `onNext` on our subject `refreshEventsSubject`, but without success.

The subject is initiated like so

`private val refreshEventsSubject = PublishSubject<Long>()`

And then we try to observe it like this

`Observable.merge(Observable.interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS), refreshEventsSubject)
    .subscribe { ... }`

We get the events from the interval every 15s, but the subject is not firing after running

`refreshEventsSubject.onNext(0)`

Any ideas appreciated.

(Everything is written in Kotlin)

Comment: In RxJava, you create a `PublishSubject` via `PublishSubject.create()` static method because of creating one via a parameterless constructor doesn't work. I don't know if RxKotlin compensates for this or not.

Comment: Yes, the Kotlin rx binding for PublishSubject looks like this

`fun <T> PublishSubject() : PublishSubject<T> = PublishSubject.create()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `refreshEventsSubject.onNext(0)` is not called from your main thread as it may cause deadlocks!

Also use http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html rather than merge as merge will emmit two events oppon calling onNext on your subject.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for AMB: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html

Specifically `emit all of the items from only the first of these Observables to emit an item or notification`.

The operator you're looking for is probably `Observable.merge`: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: Granted, it does however still not work. If we subscribe directly to the subject we get the event, but when combined/merged with the interval stream, nothing is happening.